# Consulta sql comparando dados em 3 tabelas

Tags: sql

Bom dia
Preciso realizar um select na tabela pedido comparar o id do cliente na tabela  peido com a tabela de clientes e  retonar somente os pedidos que contenham o cliente vinculado ao usuario logado

Consegui realizar o select da seguinte forma
SELECT *
FROM Pedido
JOIN Cliente ON Pedido.cliente_id = Cliente.id
WHERE Cliente.user_id = 15;

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Bom dia, parece que você já está no caminho certo com a sua consulta SQL. O seu comando SELECT está correto para obter os pedidos que têm um cliente vinculado ao usuário logado.

No entanto, é importante lembrar que, na sua consulta, você está comparando o `user_id` do cliente com o valor fixo `15`.

Supondo que você deseje vincular os pedidos ao usuário logado dinamicamente, você precisa substituir esse valor fixo pelo `user_id` real do usuário logado.

Aqui está o comando atualizado considerando essa mudança:

```
SELECT *
FROM Pedido
JOIN Cliente ON Pedido.cliente_id = Cliente.id
WHERE Cliente.user_id = <user_id_logado>;
```

Certifique-se de substituir `<user_id_logado>` pelo `user_id` correto do usuário logado em sua aplicação. Dessa forma, você obterá os pedidos que contêm o cliente vinculado ao usuário logado.

Comment: A consulta era uma mais básica para ver se retornaria os dados que eu precisava  agora estou trabalhando nesta parte para retornar os pedidos dos usuários logados e seus dados  no momento retornei somente o número do pedido preciso retornar todos os dados deles